# BertWordPieceTokenizer vs BertTokenizer from HuggingFace

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers

I have the following pieces of code and trying to understand the difference between BertWordPieceTokenizer and BertTokenizer.

## **BertWordPieceTokenizer (Rust based)**

```
from tokenizers import BertWordPieceTokenizer

sequence = "Hello, y'all! How are you Tokenizer  ?"
tokenizer = BertWordPieceTokenizer("bert-base-uncased-vocab.txt")
tokenized_sequence = tokenizer.encode(sequence)
print(tokenized_sequence)
>>>Encoding(num_tokens=15, attributes=[ids, type_ids, tokens, offsets, attention_mask, special_tokens_mask, overflowing])

print(tokenized_sequence.tokens)
>>>['[CLS]', 'hello', ',', 'y', "'", 'all', '!', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'token', '##izer', '[UNK]', '?', '[SEP]']
```

## BertTokenizer

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer
tokenizer = BertTokenizer("bert-base-cased-vocab.txt")
tokenized_sequence = tokenizer.encode(sequence)
print(tokenized_sequence)
#Output: [19082, 117, 194, 112, 1155, 106, 1293, 1132, 1128, 22559, 17260, 100, 136]
```

1. Why is encode working differently in both ? In BertWordPieceTokenizer it gives Encoding object while in BertTokenizer it gives the ids of the vocab.
2. What is the Difference between BertWordPieceTokenizer and BertTokenizer fundamentally, because as I understand BertTokenizer also uses WordPiece under the hood.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They should produce the same output when you use the same vocabulary (in your example you have used bert-base-uncased-vocab.txt and bert-base-cased-vocab.txt). The main difference is that the tokenizers from the [tokenizers](https://github.com/huggingface/tokenizers) package are faster as the tokenizers from [transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) because they are implemented in Rust.

When you modify your example you will see that they produce the same `ids` and other attributes (encoding object) while the transformers tokenizer only have produced the a list of `ids`:

```py
from tokenizers import BertWordPieceTokenizer

sequence = "Hello, y'all! How are you Tokenizer  ?"
tokenizerBW = BertWordPieceTokenizer("/content/bert-base-uncased-vocab.txt")
tokenized_sequenceBW = tokenizerBW.encode(sequence)
print(tokenized_sequenceBW)
print(type(tokenized_sequenceBW))
print(tokenized_sequenceBW.ids)
```

Output:

```
Encoding(num_tokens=15, attributes=[ids, type_ids, tokens, offsets, attention_mask, special_tokens_mask, overflowing])
<class 'Encoding'>
[101, 7592, 1010, 1061, 1005, 2035, 999, 2129, 2024, 2017, 19204, 17629, 100, 1029, 102]
```

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizer

tokenizerBT = BertTokenizer("/content/bert-base-uncased-vocab.txt")
tokenized_sequenceBT = tokenizerBT.encode(sequence)
print(tokenized_sequenceBT)
print(type(tokenized_sequenceBT))
```

Output:

```
[101, 7592, 1010, 1061, 1005, 2035, 999, 2129, 2024, 2017, 19204, 17629, 100, 1029, 102]
<class 'list'>
```

You mentioned in the comments that your questions is more about why the produced output is different. As far as I can tell this was a design decision made by the developers and there is no specific reason for that. It is also not a the case that BertWordPieceTokenizer from [tokenizers](https://github.com/huggingface/tokenizers) is an in-place replacement for the BertTokenizer from [transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers). They still use a wrapper to make it compatible with with the [transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) tokenizer API. There is a [BertTokenizerFast](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/e4aaa4580515446cd5a2972ab42fec0b95819c84/src/transformers/tokenization_bert.py#L589) class which has a "clean up" method [_convert_encoding](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/e4aaa4580515446cd5a2972ab42fec0b95819c84/src/transformers/tokenization_utils_fast.py#L142) to make the BertWordPieceTokenizer fully compatible. Therefore you have to compare the BertTokenizer example above with the following:

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast

sequence = "Hello, y'all! How are you Tokenizer  ?"
tokenizerBW = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
tokenized_sequenceBW = tokenizerBW.encode(sequence)
print(tokenized_sequenceBW)
print(type(tokenized_sequenceBW))
```

Output:

```
[101, 7592, 1010, 1061, 1005, 2035, 999, 2129, 2024, 2017, 19204, 17629, 100, 1029, 102]
<class 'list'>
```

From my perspective they have build the [tokenizers](https://github.com/huggingface/tokenizers) library independently from the [transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) library with the objective to be fast and useful.

Comment: Thats a good catch of a mistake on my part. However, taking reference from your code, my question was more around why tokenizerBT.encode(sequence) gives the token in case of BT while in case of  BWPT we had to do tokenizerBW.encode(sequence).ids to get the tokens. Is it simply a case of different implementations ...sure is confusing that one tokenizerBT.encode gives the tokens directly, but in the case of BWPT it doesn't do so

Comment: Sorry I didn't read that out in the first place. I have extended my answer to address that.